# AngularJS: Returning a promise from within .then?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, promise, resolve

I have a users service. I would like to create a method which utilizes another service I have built. There are two methods on this service. `getUser()` and `getCurrentUser()`. `getCurrentUser()` utilizes the injected service which acquires the UID. It uses the returned UID to run the `getUser()` method. My problem is that I can't get `getCurrentUser()` to return the second tier promise.

This question is a little bit difficult to explain. Here's the code...

```
svs.service("usersService", function($rootScope, $http, loginService, alertBoxService) {
  var self = this;
  self.getUser = function(identifier, column) {
    if (typeof(column) === 'undefined') column = "uid";
    return $http.get($rootScope.api + "/getUser/" + identifier + "/" + column);
  }
  self.getCurrentUser = function() {
    var currentUserPromise;
    loginService.getCurrentUid().then(
      function(response) {
        if (response.data === "false") {
          alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.unexpectedApiResponse);
        } else {
          console.log(self.getUser(response.data));
          currentUserPromise = self.getUser(response.data);
        }
      }, function(response) {
        alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.asyncFailed);
      }
    );
    return currentUserPromise;
  }
});
```

Comment: [Yes, of course](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572). But you don't need that variable at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain the promises but don't forget to chain the rejections too...

```
self.getCurrentUser = function() {
    return loginService.getCurrentUid().then(function(response) {
        if (response.data === 'false') {
            alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.unexpectedApiResponse);
            return $q.reject(response); // convert into a rejection
        }
        return self.getUser(response.data); // chain the promise resolution
    }, function(response) {
        alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.asyncFailed);
        return $q.reject(response); // chain the rejections
    });
}
```

You'll need to inject the `$q` service of course.

---

As [Bergi kindly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241790/angularjs-returning-a-promise-from-within-then/39241908#comment65820405_39241908), you can also reject the promise by throwing an error instead of using `$q.reject`, eg

```
throw response;
```

Comment: You might want to highlight the first added `return` as well, it's easily forgotten by those who learn about `then`

Comment: What are we doing with `$q` here?

Comment: Instead of using `$q.reject`, you can just re`throw` the error.

Comment: @Bergi ah yes, I forgot about that. It wouldn't be *re-throwing* though as nothing has been *caught* ;)

Comment: @Allenph when a promise rejection is handled via the second argument to `then` or `catch`, it is converted into a resolved promise unless that handler returns a rejected promise or throws an error. This lets upstream consumers know that the promise was rejected. Otherwise, they will consider it successful.

Comment: @Allenph …and successful with `undefined` as the fulfillment value, which might be unexpected and cause further exceptions downstream.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when the function `getCurrentUser` gets called, it immediately return an `undefined` variable. This is because the service is asynchronous and by the time the response is received on the service, the function call would have already returned an `undefined` variable. In order to prevent this you can add the `return` call inside the `loginService`.

Answer (score 0):

For a async function to return a promise from inside the success callback you have to return from the callback which is the promise object and then return from the main function in order to provide the promise to the caller.

Try this.

```
  svs.service("usersService", function($rootScope, $http, loginService, alertBoxService) {
  var self = this;
  self.getUser = function(identifier, column) {
    if (typeof(column) === 'undefined') column = "uid";
    return $http.get($rootScope.api + "/getUser/" + identifier + "/" + column);
  }
  self.getCurrentUser = function() {
    return loginService.getCurrentUid().then(
      function(response) {
        if (response.data === "false") {
          alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.unexpectedApiResponse);
        } else {
          console.log(self.getUser(response.data));
          return self.getUser(response.data);
        }
      }, function(response) {
        alertBoxService.trigger($rootScope.asyncFailed);
      }
    );
  }
});
```